# USB3.0 OverCurrent detection/prompt

Tags: usb

1./
How do I Ubuntu to prompt when there is in Over current occurring.
I can read from dmesg, but what if I want Ubuntu to inform me on the USB over curent?

2./
Does USB3.0 over current detection supported in Ubuntu (12.04.1 LTS)?

Please advice.

Regards,
XX Ong